# iPhone CPScatterplot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

How to make a smooth line in CPScatterplot .To make scatterplot like a curve chart.

i use this code

```
CPScatterPlot.dataSource = self;

CPScatterPlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.0f;
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this feature has now been addressed in Core Plot issue #156. As of 0.9 it has not been merged however a diff is available at http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=156

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot only draws straight line segments between your data points. You can insert extra points between your existing data, but you have to calculate the values yourself to get the desired curve. If you insert enough points, it will appear to be a smooth curve.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one May be Helped.

```
CPScatterPlot *Cps = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:graph.defaultPlotSpace.bounds]autorelease];
Cps.identifier = @" ";
Cps.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f; // if u want smooth the line 
//Cps.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blueColor]; // if u want color the line 
Cps.dataSource = self;
[graph addPlot:Cps];
```

Comment: thanks but i asked for a smooth line to make scatterplot like cure.but your code will reduce thickness of the line only